# Graph Degree and Some Condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, algebraic-graph-theory

If $G$ be a Tree with degree $(5,r,s,1,1,1,1,1) $. (I wrote degree in non-increasing order). why all of this condition is True sometimes (I means on some condition)? I try to find an example that includes all following condition. any friends could help me?

1) $G$ has a vertex of degree 2.

2) $G$ has a vertex of degree 3.

3) there is two vertices in $G$ that distance between them is 3.

4) there is two vertices in $G$ that distance between them is 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the tree? There aren't many trees fulfilling these numbers, so an exhaustive search might work.

Comment: Dear @Arthur, I want use an some novel approach.  exhaustive search  is not suitable...

Comment: If I understand correctly, the degree sequence is $(5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1)$ ?  If so, that can't be since the sum of degrees would be odd.

Comment: Dear @manuellafond, $s,r$ would be any numbers. you means 2 is false?

Comment: @NicholasMaris I think you mean to say you want to find an example for each condition? So you want 4 different examples? Is that correct?

Comment: Dear @PerryIverson exactly, infact I try to find that 1,2,3,4 is not always false in the above problem.

Comment: @NicholasMaris Then the easiest way to this would be to simply draw  trees that satisfy these conditions. You should be able to draw a tree that has degree sequence (5,2,2,1,1,1,1,1), which satisfies (1), (3), and (4), and another tree with degree sequence (5,3,1,1,1,1,1,1) that satisfies (2).

Comment: would you please submit as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The easiest way to this would be to simply draw trees that satisfy these conditions. You should be able to draw a tree that has degree sequence (5,2,2,1,1,1,1,1), which satisfies (1), (3), and (4), and another tree with degree sequence (5,3,1,1,1,1,1,1) that satisfies (2).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a graph with degree sequence $(5,r,s,1,1,1,1,1)$ has $8$ vertices.  We also know that a tree with $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges.  So any tree with this degree sequence has $7$ edges.

By the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), we must have $$5+r+s+1+1+1+1+1=2 \times 7=14.$$  I.e., $r+s=4$.

This is sufficient to exclude all possibilities except $(r,s) \in \{(3,1),(2,2)\}$, which are realizable degree sequences.  Up to isomorphism, these are the graphs (with their vertices marked by their degrees):

[image: (r,s)=(3,1); 1 graph]

and

[image: (r,s)=(2,2); 2 graphs]

The first of the three trees has no vertex of degree 2, and all distances are at most 3, which means 1. and 4. are not true in general.

The second and third have no vertices of degree 3, so 2. is not true in general.

This also means that all four conditions can not be simultaneously satisfied.

But 3. is true in general for these trees.